# how to solve tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied in remote server

Tags: java, linux, putty, winscp, suse

I am trying to install java 8 onto a remote server. I have sudo access, but when I try installing it with command `tar zxvf jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz`, I get this error message:

```
tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-javaws.png
tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-javaws.png: Cannot open: No such file or directory
jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-java.png
tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-java.png: Cannot open: No such file or directory
jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-jcontrol.png
tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-jcontrol.png: Cannot open: No such file or directory
jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/
tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/
tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/gnome-mime-text-x-java.png
tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/gnome-mime-text-x-java.png: Cannot open: No such file or directory
jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/gnome-mime-application-x-java-jnlp-file.png
tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/gnome-mime-application-x-java-jnlp-file.png: Cannot open: No such file or directory
jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/gnome-mime-application-x-java-archive.png
tar: jdk1.8.0_102: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
```

My file is located on the server. I used WinSCP to upload it
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 181435897 Aug  3 09:29 jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz

I am using putty to connect to the linux server (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64))

How can I handle this?

Comment: To discard any issue with permissions, try to move the file to /opt `mv tar zxf jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt`, give it all permissions `chmod 777 tar zxf jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz` and then execute `tar zxf jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz` from there

Comment: Did you forget to sudo your command? Try sudo tar -zxvf jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz

Comment: An update ->It seems the problem was the directory was not set up with enough space to do install once we resolved that we could do the install smoothly thanks everybody for your help